# Android app to back up SMS and call log in json format

Tags: android, json

I need a app which can backup SMS, call log (dialed call, missed call, received call) in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) format. So that this data can be used later with a programming language.

Comment: If you are OK with CSV, [SMS Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gilapps.smsshare2) can do that for SMS (but comes with some trackers like Crashlytics). [SMS Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smobile.smsbackup) saves to XML, but hasn't been updated for more than a year. [Easy SMS Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abstudio.SmsBackup) also saves an XML. More candidates in my list: [Backup SMS/MMS](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_133).

Comment: PS: [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) saves SMS, MMS and call logs to XML, which also can be used with a programming language. I've not tried any of them, hence just 2 comments instead of 1 answer.